# jQuery Validate number validation not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin. I have an input field (Benchpress) that only allows numbers. When I type letters the error message for `"required"` shows up (Please fill required field), although the field has the type number, so the error message (only numbers allowed) should come. The strange is, when I use it for a input field with type text (for testing purposes) it works perfect.

JS Code :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {    //Type=text: Here the number validation works with the correct error message
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            benchpress: {   //Type=number: Only error message for "required" even the field is filled
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            save();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="#pageone" data-ajax="false">                    

    <label for="firstname">Vorname: <span></span></label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/>

    <label for="benchpress">Bankdr&uuml;cken letzter Satz: <span></span></label>
    <input type="number" id="benchpress" name="benchpress" placeholder="Kilogramm" step="any"/>
```

Comment: There was a bug with this.   What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: You don't need `onsubmit="return false;"` since the plugin is already taking care of this for you.  And you don't need the `required` HTML5 attribute if you're already declaring the `required` rule within the `.validate()` method.

Comment: Bug or not, [my second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246784/jquery-validate-number-validation-not-working-properly?noredirect=1#comment52384230_32246784) is still valid.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to edit this